# remove table cell in xsl-fo

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I have this problem where I need to remove table cells when they are empty. But they always leave a small gap.

If the user fills out every option, the table is normal. If the user only fills out some fields then the table generates this dark horizontal line.
I suspect it is the empty cells bunching up.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" media-type="text/html" />

<xsl:template match="fwcF17Part35Page">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="part35Details"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="part35Details">
<fo:block keep-together.within-page="always">
   <fo:block padding="5pt"/>
  <fo:block font-size="16pt" text-align="left">
    Upload Documents - test
  </fo:block>
  <fo:block>
    <fo:leader leader-pattern="rule" leader-length="100%" rule-style="solid" rule-thickness="2pt"/>
  </fo:block>
  <fo:block padding="8pt"/>
  <fo:block background-color="#ebe8e8" font-size="10pt" font-weight="bold">
    Document(s)
  </fo:block>
<fo:block padding="4px" font-size="8pt" font-weight="normal" text-align="center">
  <fo:table>
    <fo:table-column column-width="50%" />
    <fo:table-column column-width="50%" />
    <fo:table-header>
      <fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" padding="2pt">
          <fo:block font-weight="bold">Document Name</fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" padding="2pt">
          <fo:block font-weight="bold">Document Type</fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
      </fo:table-row>
    </fo:table-header>
    <fo:table-body>
      <xsl:for-each select="/root/pages/page_12/sections/fwcF17DocumentUpload/data">
        <fo:table-row>
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="size > 0">
                <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" padding="2pt">
                  <fo:block>
                    <xsl:value-of select="name" />
                  </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <fo:table-cell>
                  <fo:block>
                  </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="size > 0">
                <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" padding="2pt">
                  <fo:block>
                    <xsl:value-of select="documentType" />
                  </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <fo:table-cell>
                  <fo:block>
                  </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </fo:table-row>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </fo:table-body>
  </fo:table>
</fo:block>
</fo:block>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have tried putting in:

```
<fo:table-cell visilibity="hidden">
<fo:table-cell display="none">
<fo:table-cell height="0px">
```

Wrong output when there are empty cells:

[image: problem with the cells]

Correct output when there are no empty cells:

[image: When there are no empty cells]

Comment: Have you tried removing all the white space in your fo:block and make them self closing elements? What FO engine are you rendering with?

Comment: Your question needs more clarity. I suggest you also show a sample source-xml and the expected result-xml. When the thicker horizontal line in the picture is the problem, I suppose you need to filter rows not cells.

Comment: Since it makes no sense to have one table cell in a row with "no size" I can only assume you want to remove the row if all the cells are size="0". Also the picture you show could never come from the template you post since you output only one cell in that row, either an empty one or one with the "name" value.

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: As @SiebeJongebloed commented, please also add a sample of your `<data>` XML that will and won't generate table cells in your result.

Comment: I apologize everyone. I am totally unfamiliar with this entire xsl topic. I don't even know what <data> you are talking about.

Comment: `<data>` is the source XML element that you are transforming to make the XSL-FO table rows. Your XSLT includes `<xsl:for-each select="/root/pages/page_12/sections/fwcF17DocumentUpload/data">`. The value of `select` is an XPath that is selecting some number of `<data>` elements (the `data` in the last step in the XPath expression). When answering questions, it can help to see the relevant input as well as the relevant parts of the stylesheet and the incorrect output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only create `fo:table-row` if your data fulfills the filter  `size > 0`

You can do that by adding a predicate to your for-each.
In addition you can use that same predicate in the match, te ensure that there will be not a invalid `fo:table` constructed.
The xslt would then look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" media-type="text/html" />
  
  <xsl:template match="fwcF17Part35Page">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="part35Details"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="part35Details[/root/pages/page_12/sections/fwcF17DocumentUpload/data[size &gt; 0]]">
    <fo:block keep-together.within-page="always">
      <fo:block padding="5pt"/>
      <fo:block font-size="16pt" text-align="left">
        Upload Documents - test
      </fo:block>
      <fo:block>
        <fo:leader leader-pattern="rule" leader-length="100%" rule-style="solid" rule-thickness="2pt"/>
      </fo:block>
      <fo:block padding="8pt"/>
      <fo:block background-color="#ebe8e8" font-size="10pt" font-weight="bold">
        Document(s)
      </fo:block>
      <fo:block padding="4px" font-size="8pt" font-weight="normal" text-align="center">
        <fo:table>
          <fo:table-column column-width="50%" />
          <fo:table-column column-width="50%" />
          <fo:table-header>
            <fo:table-row>
              <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" padding="2pt">
                <fo:block font-weight="bold">Document Name</fo:block>
              </fo:table-cell>
              <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" padding="2pt">
                <fo:block font-weight="bold">Document Type</fo:block>
              </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
          </fo:table-header>
          <fo:table-body>
            <xsl:for-each select="/root/pages/page_12/sections/fwcF17DocumentUpload/data[size &gt; 0]">
              <fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" padding="2pt">
                  <fo:block>
                    <xsl:value-of select="name" />
                  </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" padding="2pt">
                  <fo:block>
                    <xsl:value-of select="documentType" />
                  </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
              </fo:table-row>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
      </fo:block>
    </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It would be really helpful if you would add a minimal xml-source-sample to your question to better understand your xslt.

I.e: your template match: `<xsl:template match="part35Details">` looks somewhat strange. The template does not use the context.

Comment: This causes error if there are no elements:
ValidationException: \"fo:table-body\" is missing child elements.

Comment: I have adjusted the answer, but be aware that your question did not include this option. To really give you a good answer, it is better to also share your source-xml.

Comment: I found an easier way to do it. I just added a blank fo:table-row at the bottom of the table. So you won't see the double line.